# Getting variable in async onload using callback Angular 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, asynchronous

I am trying to upload an image and return its `src` using `FileReader`.

```
fileUpload(event) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
      getImgSrc(fr.result)
    }
  }

getImgSrc(src) {
  console.log(src);
}
```

This returns `Cannot find name 'getImgSrc'`

However if I do `this.getImgSrc(fr.result)` I receive error `getImgSrc does not exist on type'MSBaseReader'` of course because the context of `this`. How do I access the method `getImgSrc` to return my async variable?

Comment: fr.onload = this.getImgSrc;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the context (`this`) when you use non-arrow-functions (`function() { ... }`.

Since `getImgSrc` is a method and not a function in the global scope, you have to call it with `this`:

```
fr.onload = () => this.getImgSrc(fr.result);
```

If `onload` passes you the result of the image upload, you can use:

```
fr.onload = result => this.getImgSrc(result);
```

In case you did not omit this from the code in your question, you also *forgot to actually start reading* the file using one of the read methods:

```
fr.readAsBinaryString(file)   // to get a string with bytes (0-255)
fr.readAsText(file, encoding) // to get a text string
fr.readAsDataURL(file)        // to get a DataURL
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file)    // to get an ArrayBuffer object
```

Comment: Yes, I had readAsDataURL and have accidentally deleted that somewhere along the way. Let me try to fix

Comment: Perfect! I will edit your answer with final solution

Answer (score 2):

Try using ES6 lambda arrow syntax to preserve the context of `this` within the handler.

```
fileUpload(event) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => this.getImgSrc(fr.result);    
  }

getImgSrc(src) {
  console.log(src);
}
```

Regarding nothing being logged, try targeting the `result` of [FileReader.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) from the event passed to `onload` in the following way:

```
fileUpload(event) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (event) => this.getImgSrc(event);    
  }

getImgSrc(event) {
  console.log(event.target.result);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Nothing seems to be logged to the console

Comment: Are you sure that `result` property of `fr` has a value at the time `onload` executes?

Comment: I believe so. I am able to access the variable if i store it in `localStorage` like so: `fr.onload = function() {
      localStorage['myImage'] = fr.result;
    }`